# Are SQL Server defaults generated before or after the insert?

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I have a table that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE bob
    (ID INT IDENTITY,
    blah VARBINARY(MAX),
    ts DATETIME2 DEFAULT GETUTCDATE())
```

Let's assume that this statement

```
INSERT INTO dbo.bob
        ( blah )
VALUES  (
          @blarg
          )
```

takes 10 seconds to complete.

If the time at the start of the insertion is t.  Will ts have t or t + 10 seconds on the newly created row?  In other words, are defaults generated at the start of the insert or the end of the insert (or some other rule)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GETUTCDATE` is a [runtime constant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions/)

It will be calculated once at the start and the same value used throughout for all rows inserted by the statement.

However if you were to wrap it in a scalar UDF calling `GETUTCDATE` and change the default to call the UDF instead you might see different values as then it is evaluated row by row.

For a single row statement I guess it depends where the 10 second delay is. If it can't compile the plan for 10 seconds it won't start executing until then so that will be the time. If it starts executing and waits for a lock I would imagine it should be allocated a time before the wait as the runtime constant should already be resolved.

Comment: You are incorrect.  I've just double checked to verify. When used as a default constraint, GETDATE and GETDATEUTC are rerun with every insert statement.

Comment: @Cogman you haven't read my answer properly then. It certainly doesn't make any claim that the value will persist between statements. I'm talking about the case where you insert multiple rows in a single statement and the insert statement takes 10 seconds.

Comment: My mistake.  You are right :) .  I reread your statement and it makes sense. Sorry about the confusion.